# Wordpress Site on Windows Server

Tags: wordpress, iis, windows-server-2008

I have a website that I need to update which is written in asp. I believe it is a windows server.

I wanted to rewrite this site in wordpress. Is it possible to do that on a windows server?

If possible, what is the best way to build in wordpress on windows server?

Should I just buy another hosting account with linux and repoint the dns when I am done?

Comment: Needs more specific info. Which version of IIS are you running? Is PHP installed on it?

Comment: Wordpress works on windows , linux and even in apple os
so don't worry about it this link may help you [http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress](http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I frequently run WordPress on my Windows 7 development machine.  It's actually not all that difficult, and I once even installed WordPress on a Windows Server hosted through GoDaddy.

The things you'll need to set up on the server (if they aren't already):

- PHP
- MySQL
- Apache (if you want to serve pages through Apache rather than IIS)

If you want, the Windows Web Platform Installer can actually automate much of the process for you.  It will download WordPress (and its dependencies) and configure everything for the server.

There are step-by-step instructions for using the web installer located on the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Easy_5_Minute_WordPress_Installation_on_Windows)

If you want an alternative, you can install a [BitNami application stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/wordpress) for WordPress (that includes PHP, MySQL, and Apache) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Googling "Wordpress on Windows" should give you a good overview.

- [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress) officially claims WP runs fine on IIS, and (if I read it right) is even one-click installable with WebMatrix (whatever that is).
- [Learn.iis.net](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/280/install-wordpress-on-iis/) has an (older but probably still valid) article detailing the steps necessary to manually install WordPress on IIS.

If you don't know the specifics of the IIS that is running, and don't know how to administer the package you're supposed to install all this on, you *may* be better off getting a fresh Linux package. However, I'm sure it's possible to get WordPress to run on IIS in this day and age - it may take some tweaking though.